# The buttons on Google play cards (CardView & RecycleView)

Tags: android, button, view, google-play

I've just started working on `CardView` and `RecycleView` and I want to know what are the side buttons that looks like 3 dots on every card and how to implement it.

Cards like we see in Google Play Store app, where there are cards with buttons.
I don't have enough reputation to post a picture but I'm posting [this link](http://www.dropbox.com/s/ldkibtg7ej7007o/Screenshot_2015-01-15-12-27-30.png?dl=0) where you can see it and the buttons are marked in red circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html).

It's a new Android Pattern to generalize ActionBar to use in multiple enviroments, like Cards and others.

How to use it: http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Comment: thanks i got it but still i'm not able to find any syntax that can add toolbar into the cards !

Answer (score 1):

I don't think adding a `toolbar` on every card is a good idea (as suggested in another answer). As you can see in the image itself, there is no space for a full-width toolbar due to images taking up width of layout. So the best way will be to implement it using an [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html). Just add an `imageButton` on top and configure it to open a drop down menu or dialog or whatever.
P.S. Yes, there can be multiple toolbars according to new material design guidelines but having one on every card is probably not a good idea. Especially when it can't even be a full-width component.

Comment: actually i want to implement many cards by array list !  So that i dont need to add as many buttons mannually so is there any other way ??

Comment: You won't have to. You said you are using a custom `recyclerView` right? So you'll just have to add it once in your custom layout. And it will of course be copied to all your items in `recyclerView`.

Comment: can you give any of the example ??

Comment: Have you built the rest of your card? If yes, then just put an `imageButton` just right to your heading of card.